# systemd unit started multiple instances instead of one

Tags: bash, systemd

I'm trying to setup a systemd unit that should restart a bash script if it fails.

```
[Unit]
Description=Bash script Service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/simple/bash/script.sh'
```

But from `systemctl status the_bash_script.service` it seems that it is started with multiple instances:

```
● the_bash_script.service - Bash script Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/the_bash_script.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-11-03 18:16:53 CET; 3 years 6 months ago
 Main PID: 1766 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/the_bash_script.service
           ├─1766 /bin/bash -c '/bin/bash -c '/simple/bash/script.sh'
           └─1778 /bin/bash -c '/bin/bash -c '/simple/bash/script.sh'
```

Why there are 2 pids 1766 and 1778?
Can I allow only one instance at time?

If this is the content of the_bash_script.service I don't need thata multiple instance are run at the same time:

```
#!/bin/bash


while [ true ]; do
    cat /dev/virtual  | nc -v 192.168.1.1 5005    
    sleep 5s
done

exit
```

Comment: Please put in your question why you think that forking off another process is not a function of whatever your shell script does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/simple/bash/script.sh'` contains  `/bin/bash -c`
which starts a bash shell with command `/simple/bash/script.sh` and then again when the script starts executing `/simple/bash/script.sh` it will start another bash shell  i think.

Try this in your service file :

```
ExecStart=/simple/bash/script.sh
```

Also add the below lines and try:

```
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
```